# Faster way to draw huge amount of triangle / height map (Direct 3D, C++)

Tags: c++, performance, 3d, direct3d

I'm currently writting a 3D visualization tool for a scientific application and I am facing a performance problem.
I have a relatively large grid (~ 1000 rows x 1000 columns) and for each point of this grid I have a physical value that I want to represent as height (for instance: temperature).

Here is an example of what I am trying to draw with white gaussian noise:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM23m.jpg

I am using DirectX 9 to draw my scene. I basiclaly draw a bunch of triangles with the (X,Y) coordinate being a point on the grid, and the Z coordinate being the physical measurement at that point.

Here are the operations that I do on each frame:

- I create a vertex buffer (CreateVertexBuffer()) and an index buffer (CreateIndexBuffer()) (the data changes on each frame, but the size of the data does not)
- I lock them
- I fill the two buffers properly, including assigning a color depending on the value (high value are red, low value are blue)
- I unlock them
- I set the stream source (SetStreamSource()), set the indices (SetIndices()) and draw the triangles (as a triangle strip)
- I release the two buffers

My problem is that the frame rate is not as high as expected.
I achieve ~30fps for ~2 millions triangles drawn on a Nvidia GTX 770 (& Intel Core i7 4770k if that matters) when I want to have at least 60fps.

Is there a better way to do what I am doing or my problem is that the number of triangle is too large ?
Will I get better performance if I use DirectX 11 ?

Thank you for your help.

Edit here is a stand-alone simplified code:

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
    #include <math.h>
    #include <windowsx.h>
    #include <d3d9.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <random>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <io.h>

    #define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
    #define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600
    #define COLORMAPSIZE 256

    #pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")

    #define DEG2RAD(x) (x* (float)M_PI/180.0f)
    #define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)


    std::default_random_engine randGenerator;

    // global declarations
    LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;

    const int Nrows = 1000, Ncols = 2000;
    float indexAz=DEG2RAD(90), indexEl = DEG2RAD(60), distance=80;
    const float dataAmplitude = 5.f;
    std::vector<float> dataBuffer;

    typedef struct D3DXVECTOR3 : public D3DVECTOR
    {
    public:
        FLOAT x,y,z;
        D3DXVECTOR3() {};
        D3DXVECTOR3( FLOAT xx, FLOAT yy, FLOAT zz ) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) {};

    } D3DXVECTOR3, *LPD3DXVECTOR3;

    typedef struct {
        float x, y, z;
        D3DCOLOR color;
    } Vertex;


    void initD3D(HWND hWnd);
    void resetD3D(HWND hWnd);
    void render_frame(void);
    void cleanD3D(void);
    void draw_graphics(void);


    // the WindowProc function prototype
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    void CreateConsole() {

      CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO consoleInfo;
      int consoleHandleR, consoleHandleW ;
      long stdioHandle;
      FILE *fptr;

      AllocConsole();
      std::wstring strW = L"Dev Console";
      SetConsoleTitleW( strW.c_str() );

      EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), FALSE), SC_CLOSE , MF_GRAYED);
      DrawMenuBar(GetConsoleWindow());

      GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &consoleInfo );

      stdioHandle = (long)GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
      consoleHandleR = _open_osfhandle( stdioHandle, _O_TEXT );
      fptr = _fdopen( consoleHandleR, "r" );
      *stdin = *fptr;
      setvbuf( stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

      stdioHandle = (long) GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
      consoleHandleW = _open_osfhandle( stdioHandle, _O_TEXT );
      fptr = _fdopen( consoleHandleW, "w" );
      *stdout = *fptr;
      setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

      stdioHandle = (long)GetStdHandle( STD_ERROR_HANDLE );
      *stderr = *fptr;
      setvbuf( stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    }

    // Generate a random number following a uniform distribution
    double rand(const double inf=0, const double sup=1) {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(inf,sup);
        return distribution(randGenerator);
    }

    // Update the buffer with new data
    void UpdateDataBuffer()
    {
        static bool firstCall = true;

        if (firstCall) //fill the whole buffer
        {
            for(unsigned k = 0 ; k < Nrows*Ncols ; k++)
                dataBuffer[k] = (float)rand(0,dataAmplitude);
            firstCall = false;
        } else { // remove the first column, shift the whole buffer and update the last column

            memmove(&dataBuffer[0], &dataBuffer[Nrows], (Ncols-1)*Nrows*sizeof(float));
            for(unsigned k= Nrows*(Ncols-1) ; k < Nrows*Ncols ; k++)
                dataBuffer[k] = (float)rand(0,dataAmplitude);
        }
    }

    // the entry point for any Windows program
    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                       int nCmdShow)
    {
        CreateConsole();
        randGenerator.seed( GetTickCount() );
        dataBuffer.resize(Nrows * Ncols);

        HWND hWnd;
        WNDCLASSEX wc;

        ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

        wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

        RegisterClassEx(&wc);

        hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "WindowClass", "Our Direct3D Program",
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                              NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

        ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

        initD3D(hWnd);

        MSG msg;
        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
        LARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;
        float fps = 0.f;
        float NFramAvg = 1.0f/10.0f, totalElapsedTime = 0.0f;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);

        while(TRUE)
        {
            while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }

            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            UpdateDataBuffer();
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
            render_frame();
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);
            fps = fps - NFramAvg*fps + NFramAvg* frequency.QuadPart / (t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart);
            totalElapsedTime +=  (t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart)*1000.0f / frequency.QuadPart;;

            if (totalElapsedTime > 1000) {
                printf("FPS = %g\n", fps);
                totalElapsedTime = 0.0;
            }
        }

        cleanD3D();

        return msg.wParam;
    }


    // this is the main message handler for the program
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        static int clickX, clickY;
        static bool down = false;
        switch(message)
        {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            if (!down)
            {
                clickX = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
                clickY = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
            }
            down = true;
            break;
        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            down = false;
            break;
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            if (down)
            {
                int dx = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam) - clickX;
                int dy = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) - clickY;

                indexAz += dx*DEG2RAD(0.5f);
                if (indexEl + dy*DEG2RAD(0.5f) < M_PI_2 && indexEl + dy*DEG2RAD(0.5f) > -M_PI_2)
                    indexEl += dy*DEG2RAD(0.5f);

                clickX += dx;
                clickY += dy;
            }

            break;
        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        {
            int zDelta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam); //scroll power
            distance -= 2*zDelta/120.f;
            distance = max(1.0f, distance);
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
        case WM_SIZE:
            if (d3ddev)
                resetD3D(hWnd);
            break;

        }

        return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }


    // this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
    void initD3D(HWND hWnd)
    {
        d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

        D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;


        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

        ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
        d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
        d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
        d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
        d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
        d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = rect.right - rect.left;
        d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = rect.bottom -rect.top;
        d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
        d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;


        d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                          D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                          hWnd,
                          D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                          &d3dpp,
                          &d3ddev);

        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);    // turn off the 3D lighting
        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);    // turn off culling
        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);    // turn on the z-buffer
    }

    void resetD3D(HWND hWnd)
    {
        D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

        ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
        d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
        d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
        d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
        d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
        d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = rect.right - rect.left;
        d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = rect.bottom -rect.top;
        d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
        d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;


        if (d3dpp.BackBufferWidth && d3dpp.BackBufferHeight)
        {
            d3ddev->Reset(&d3dpp);

            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
        }

        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);    // turn off the 3D lighting
        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);    // turn off culling
        d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);    // turn on the z-buffer

    }

    D3DXVECTOR3 *D3DVec3Subtract(D3DXVECTOR3 *pOut, const D3DXVECTOR3 *pV1,const D3DXVECTOR3 *pV2)
    {
        pOut->x = pV1->x - pV2->x;
        pOut->y = pV1->y - pV2->y;
        pOut->z = pV1->z - pV2->z;
        return pOut;
    }

    D3DXVECTOR3* D3DVec3Normalize(D3DXVECTOR3 *pOut,const D3DXVECTOR3 *pV)
    {
        FLOAT norm = sqrt( pV->x * pV->x +  pV->y * pV->y + pV->z * pV->z );
        pOut->x = pV->x / norm;
        pOut->y = pV->y / norm;
        pOut->z = pV->z / norm;
        return pOut;
    }

    D3DXVECTOR3* D3DVec3Cross(D3DXVECTOR3 *pOut,const D3DXVECTOR3 *pV1,const D3DXVECTOR3 *pV2)
    {
        pOut->x = pV1->y*pV2->z - pV1->z*pV2->y;
        pOut->y = pV1->z*pV2->x - pV1->x*pV2->z;
        pOut->z = pV1->x*pV2->y - pV1->y*pV2->x;
        return pOut;
    }

    FLOAT D3DVec3Dot(const D3DXVECTOR3 *pV1,const D3DXVECTOR3 *pV2)
    {
        return pV1->x * pV2->x + pV1->y * pV2->y + pV1->z * pV2->z;
    }


    D3DMATRIX* D3DMatrixLookAtLH(D3DMATRIX *pOut,const D3DXVECTOR3 *pEye,const D3DXVECTOR3 *pAt,const D3DXVECTOR3 *pUp)
    {
        D3DXVECTOR3 right, rightn, up, upn, vec, vec2;

        D3DVec3Subtract(&vec2, pAt, pEye);
        D3DVec3Normalize(&vec, &vec2);
        D3DVec3Cross(&right, pUp, &vec);
        D3DVec3Cross(&up, &vec, &right);
        D3DVec3Normalize(&rightn, &right);
        D3DVec3Normalize(&upn, &up);
        pOut->m[0][0] = rightn.x;
        pOut->m[1][0] = rightn.y;
        pOut->m[2][0] = rightn.z;
        pOut->m[3][0] = -D3DVec3Dot(&rightn,pEye);
        pOut->m[0][1] = upn.x;
        pOut->m[1][1] = upn.y;
        pOut->m[2][1] = upn.z;
        pOut->m[3][1] = -D3DVec3Dot(&upn, pEye);
        pOut->m[0][2] = vec.x;
        pOut->m[1][2] = vec.y;
        pOut->m[2][2] = vec.z;
        pOut->m[3][2] = -D3DVec3Dot(&vec, pEye);
        pOut->m[0][3] = 0.0f;
        pOut->m[1][3] = 0.0f;
        pOut->m[2][3] = 0.0f;
        pOut->m[3][3] = 1.0f;
        return pOut;
    }

    D3DMATRIX* D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(D3DMATRIX *pOut, const FLOAT fovy, const FLOAT Aspect, const FLOAT zn, const FLOAT zf)
    {
        FLOAT yScale = tanf((float)M_PI_2 - fovy/2);
        FLOAT xScale = yScale /Aspect;
        memset(pOut,0, sizeof(*pOut));

        pOut->_11 = xScale;
        pOut->_22 = yScale;
        pOut->_33 = zf/(zf-zn);
        pOut->_34 = 1;
        pOut->_43 = -zn*zf/(zf-zn);

        return pOut;
    }

    long GetColor(const float x, const float inf, const float sup)
    {
        BYTE c =(BYTE)( 255 * (x-inf)/(sup-inf) );
        return D3DCOLOR_XRGB(c,c,c);
    }

    // this is the function that puts the 3D models into video RAM
    void draw_graphics(void)
    {
        static long colorTab[COLORMAPSIZE] = {0,};
        static std::vector<Vertex> tmp;
        static LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 v_buffer = NULL;
        static LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9 i_buffer = NULL;
        static unsigned NVertex = 0;

        // Create empty IDirect3DTexture9
        const unsigned MN = Nrows*Ncols;
        unsigned k=0;

        if (MN > tmp.size())
            tmp.resize( MN );

        if (colorTab[0] == 0) // if colortab empty, fill it
        {
            for(int i=0 ; i < COLORMAPSIZE ;i++)
                colorTab[i] = GetColor((float)i, (float)0, (float)(COLORMAPSIZE-1));
        }

        if (!v_buffer)
            d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(MN*sizeof(Vertex), 0,D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE,D3DPOOL_MANAGED,&v_buffer,NULL);

        float factor =  (COLORMAPSIZE-1.0f)/dataAmplitude;
        for (k=0 ; k < MN ; k++)
        {
            if (dataBuffer[k] >= dataAmplitude)
                tmp[k].color = colorTab[COLORMAPSIZE-1];
            else if (dataBuffer[k] <= 0)
                tmp[k].color = colorTab[0];
            else
                tmp[k].color = colorTab[(int)( ( dataBuffer[k])*factor )];
        }

        float M_2 = Nrows/2.0f, N_2 = Ncols/2.0f;
        k=0;
        for (unsigned n=0 ; n < Ncols ; n++)
        {
            for (unsigned m=0 ; m < Nrows ; m++, k++)
            {
                tmp[k].x = M_2 - m;
                tmp[k].z = n - N_2;
                tmp[k].y = dataBuffer[k];
            }
        }

        Vertex* pVoid;
        v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
        memcpy(pVoid, &tmp[0], MN*sizeof(Vertex));
        v_buffer->Unlock();


        if (!i_buffer)
            d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(3*2*(Nrows-1)*(Ncols-1)*sizeof(DWORD), 0, D3DFMT_INDEX32, D3DPOOL_MANAGED,&i_buffer,NULL);

        DWORD *indices;
        i_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&indices, 0);

        k=0;
        for (unsigned n=0 ; n < Ncols-1 ; n++)
        {
            if (n!=0)
                indices[k++] = n*Nrows;

            for (unsigned m=0 ; m < Nrows-1 ; m++)
            {
                indices[k++] = m   + n*Nrows;
                indices[k++] = m   + (n+1)*Nrows;
            }
            indices[k++] =  Nrows-2   + (n+1)*Nrows;
        }
        NVertex = k;
        i_buffer->Unlock(); 

        d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(Vertex));
        d3ddev->SetIndices(i_buffer);
        d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 0, MN, 0, NVertex-2);
        //printf("%d triangle drawn\n", NVertex-2);

        //i_buffer->Release();
        //v_buffer->Release();
    }

    // this is the function used to render a single frame
    void render_frame(void)
    {
        d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
        d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
        d3ddev->BeginScene();
        d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

        // set the view transform
        D3DMATRIX matView;    // the view transform matrix
        float R = distance*25;
        D3DMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
            &D3DXVECTOR3 (R*sin(indexAz)*cos(indexEl), R*sin(indexEl),R*cos(indexAz)*cos(indexEl)),    // the camera position
            &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),      // the look-at position
            &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));    // the up direction
        d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);    // set the view transform to matView 

        // set the projection transform
        D3DMATRIX matProjection;    // the projection transform matrix
        D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
                                   DEG2RAD(45),    // the horizontal field of view
                                   (FLOAT)SCREEN_WIDTH / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT, // aspect ratio
                                   0.001f,   // the near view-plane
                                   100000.f);    // the far view-plane
        d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProjection); // set the projection
        indexAz += DEG2RAD(0.1f);
        draw_graphics();
        d3ddev->EndScene(); 
        d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }

    // this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
    void cleanD3D(void)
    {
        d3ddev->Release();
        d3d->Release();
    }
```

Comment: I'd say that sending your data to the GPU is the issue, not the drawing itself.

Comment: What test can I do to see if it comes from the drawing or the data ?

Comment: Scratch that, I had another piece of code after that was a bottleneck.
Here are the values:
Buffer updated each frame & drawn: 20fps
Same buffer redrawn each frame   : 25 fps
Buffer updated each frame but not drawn: 70 fps
Nothing done: 130fps (which is suspiciously low!)

Comment: Yeah, should be getting approximately 1 million FPS with nothing, are you sure you're using the GPU you listed? Sometimes it defaults to an integrated one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, because you say you're IO bound, the best thing would be to reduce the amount of data you send to the GPU every update.

If you're targeting SM 3.0 or higher you can use vertex texture fetching to sample the height from a texture that you update every frame. This is a lot easier on the input assembler and on BW.

To do this most easily, you might want to change your vertex data, instead of supplying a float3 with xyz, you might want to supply a uint2 with just xz, this way you can directly fetch from the texture without doing a float to int conversion in your shader.

as a side note, there is very little reason for you to write a vertex's color to your VB if it can be trivially derived from its position, it would be less bw to calculate it in the shader with a lerp or some other blending operation.

I've done this very thing for a project of mine, and the speedup is massive on my GTX 480. Brought me from spending 50ms on rendering heightmaps to around 1ms.

Comment: I agree with you. To my knowledge we cannot write shaders in DirectX 9, hence my question about DirectX 11.
I think I will rewrite my application with DX11.

Comment: D3D9 does actually support shaders. In fact, it can go all the way up to Shader Model 3.0, which is what you'd need for vertex texture fetch to be a standard feature. If you go with DX11, you'll have to write a lot more boilerplate to get your renderer going, who while it's a better option in the long run, the switch will maybe take you a lot longer than just adding a shader pair to your current program. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something you don't need to lock your index buffer and update it, you are setting it to the same values anyways. That will get rid of that 1000x2000 loop.

Also I wouldn't update the vertex buffer everyframe if the data isn't changing everyframe. Just update it whenever the data is actually updated.

Comment: You are right, I can allocate & fill the index buffer only once since its static.
However I need to update the vertex at each frame simply because the vertex are updated 60 times per second.
Unfortunately I am bandwidth limited here.

Comment: Would using a dynamic vertex buffer help? D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC? instead of a managed vertex buffer.